# SQL Server 2008 sort date in ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, row-number

The following query generate an error message

```
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 'AccessionNumber' THEN  [AccessionNumber]
    WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN  CreatedDate
END))AS RowNumber
```

Where

```
@SortBy VARCHAR(50) = 'AccessionNumber'
```

passed as parameter.

Error :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done like this.

```
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (
            -- Dynamic sorting
            ORDER BY 
               CASE WHEN  @SortBy = 'AccessionNumber'  THEN [AccessionNumber] END Asc ,
               CASE WHEN  @SortBy = 'CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate END  Asc
              ) as  RowNo
```

ie : First Order By one colunm THEN BY another .... like this..

Comment: It doesn't **have** to be done like that at all as my answer shows.

Answer (score 4):

All branches of the `case` expression will be cast to the data type of the branch with [the highest precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

`datetime` has higher precedence than `varchar` so it will try and cast `AccessionNumber` values to `datetime`. You can use an explicit cast to `sql_variant` as below.

```
CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 'AccessionNumber' THEN  cast([AccessionNumber] as sql_variant)
    WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN  CreatedDate
END
```

You should be aware this kind of dynamic sort condition will not use an index to avoid a sort.